# How to Change Sharepoint Port

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

I have a Sharepoint web application that I want to change the port it is running on. I am not sure how to do that as It seems that it is not enough to just go to the IIS console and change the web application port. I guess I need to do certain changes in the sharepoint Central administration console as well.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do it would be to extend the web application to a new IIS website on the new port, then unextend it from the old IIS website.